# R language setting colors in map.scale (maps package)?

Tags: r, colors, scale, terra

I'm here with a stupid question after googleing for a while.
I need to do a map more or less like this one:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(terra)
library(maps)
world <- vect(ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf"))
plot(world)
map.scale(38, -20.7, relwidth = 0.15, ratio = F, 
          cex = 0.8, metric = TRUE, col = "red")
```

Which yields:

[image]

However, I need that both the text and line of the scale in red, while it keeps the line in black whatever I do... For example, I also tried `border = "red"` unsuccessfuly... Any suggestion?

**PLEASE NOTE:** I don't plan to use ggplot, I could change the scale source as much. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290232/change-map-scale-bar-color-r

Answer (score 1):

The result is not exactly the same, but you could use

```
terra::sbar(10000, col="red", lonlat=TRUE)
```